# How do I add a counter to dynamically generate the id number?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've added this Jquery to a .js file and it works.
All that is left, and I have trouble figuring out, is to add a counter. The counter could then be added to the `id="accordingNR"` , `data-parent="accordionNR"` (where it says 'NR') and other necessary references .

Also, since i'm a beginner at coding, I'd appreciate any tips on if this can be written more efficiently?

```
$('.speaker-info').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap("<div class=\"accordion\" id=\"accordion\"></div>");
});

$('.speaker-info h4').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(2)')
           .andSelf()
           .wrapAll("<div class=\"accordion-heading\"><a class=\"accordion-toggle\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapseOne\"> </a></div>");
});

$('.accordion-heading').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.accordion-heading')
           .wrapAll("<div id=\"collapseOne\" class=\"accordion-body collapse in\"><div class=\"accordion-inner\"></div></div>");
    $(this).next()
           .andSelf()
           .wrapAll('<div class=\"accordion-group\"></div>');
});
```

I'm creating the [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) from Bootstrap via Jquery. Unfortunately this is the only way to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method generates its own counter, if you include arguments in the callback function:

```
$('.speaker-info').each(function(i,el){
    // i is an automatic counter that starts at zero,
    // el is the DOM element being acted on (same as 'this')
    var id = "accordingNR_"+i;
```